# What is Basic Difference between Salesforce IOT Explorer and IOT Scale?

Tags: iot, iot-explorer

I am learning about Salesforce IOT and found that Salesforce has two edition for IOT as below :

- IOT Explorer
- IOT Scale

If someone has worked on it, can you suggest the basic difference between these editions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce IoT Scale Edition lets you set up business logic to take meaningful actions based on customer context and real-time events while Salesforce IoT Explorer Edition is used to process event messages and integrate them with Salesforce records

Some more info here: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/214/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/iot_all.pdf